# Working with EF for Oracle database. "Schema specified is not valid"

Tags: entity-framework, oracle10g, entity-framework-5

The field in Oracle database is of NUMBER(5), and when I generate EF models from the oracle database, it converts the field into "Int16".
There are some of the rows for that field having values such as "50000", etc, so Int16 is throwing error for obvious reasons.
Now I tried changing it to Int32, and also Decimal in EF models, but it is now giving an error saying -

> Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.Decimal[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=,Scale=]' of member
>   'Field1' in type
>   'MyApp_Models.MyTable' is not compatible
>   with 'OracleEFProvider.number

Any idea what is wrong here, and what is possible solution of this?

Any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: any idea on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your type to just INT instead of INT32.  See if that works.